# Using Android's ViewPager, is it possible to disable the "bowing" effect that occurs when a user attempts to swipe when there are no pages left

Tags: android, android-viewpager

In the screenshot, the user is on Page 1 of the ViewPager (the fragment is in red). The screenshot is taken as the user swipes finger from left to right, trying to swipe to a previous tab. Since it's the first page, there is no page before it so Android shows this weird "bowing" transform. Is there any way to disable this effect?

[image: ViewPager Bowing]

Comment: What are you planning on replacing it with, to signify to the user that they cannot swipe further in that direction?

Comment: Nothing, it just clashes with the design. This is simply a carousel with steps introducing how to use the app. The first page is a title that says "Swipe to learn more about the app ->" with n right arrow. The next page has 1. Lorem Ipsum. The page after has 2. Lorem Ipsum. etc until the last page which also concludes with takes that says "... and that's it!". So UX wise, it'll be fine.

Comment: ptitvinou's link seems to have fixed it. I did run across that link earlier but their description of the issue was different from mine so I was mistaken that it was a different issue. He reports a faded edge while I'm reporting a bowing effect, but they seem to just be different manifestations of the same problem. Thanks ptitvinou!